# What does “Emergency blame game” on Iraq mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

New Yorker magazine (June 14) reports as follows under the headline, “Senator, John McCain calls for **emergency blame game** on Iraq.”:

> “Citing the deteriorating situation in the war-torn nation, Senator John McCain (R-Arizona) on Saturday called for Congress to convene an **emergency blame game** on Iraq.
> [..]
>   McCain said that he hoped Congress would act swiftly to assign blame to a long list of culprits he identified, including President Obama, the Joint Chiefs, the media, and everyone who did not vote for him in the 2008 election.”
>   http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/borowitzreport/2014/06/mccain-calls-for-emergency-blame-game-on-iraq.html

What is “Emergency Blame Game”? Does it have any legal effects, I mean, binding power of the law?

What does the word “game” here represent for? Why is it “game,” not act, initiative, resolution, or campaign?

Comment: It is *sardonic*. The tip-off is the bit "...and everyone who did not vote for him in 2008 election." It's clearly not possible.

Comment: From the "quotation": "detriorating"? "He hoped Congress to act swiftly..."? "conprits"?  "in 2008 election.”? From your own text: "...represent for?" Tsk,tsk,tsk... ;)

Comment: EM Fields: there were more glaring typo's and other mistakes - but it seems the blog was edited, so I re-quoted :)

Comment: It's worth noting that the [Borowitz Report](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/borowitzreport/) is indeed a satirical blog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Playing the blame game* is a meeting where a group of people are confronted with a difficult situation and instead of working together to meet the challenge they organize themselves in an adversarial way and try to assign blame. It's a game because it's childish. It's also a game because there are winner and losers. The winners don't have to help to solve the problem because it's not their fault, the losers get blamed, and have the burden of solving the problem. Also *blame* and *game* rhymes, and rhyming or alliteration is always a good reason for coining a phrase in English.